# If mousedown then trigger mousemove else do nothing

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have a technical issue and I am not sure what the best way is to solve it.

Basically im working on an audio progress bar where the user can change the position of the song. This should be done by either clicking or by keeping the mousedown and moving it.

```
elem.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event){
  elem.removeEventListener("mousemove", fn);
});

elem.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
  elem.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
      // Stuff to do
  }, fn);
});
```

So essentially:

If mouse is held down and then moved do something. If mouse is released prevent the trigger of `mousemove`.

I know if I continue with this it might work but it looks like a horrible mess to me. I dont want to pick up bad habits.

#### My question is: How do I make make this work using best practices?

Note: I also tried the following:

```
function fn(event) {
if(event.button == 0) {
      elem.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
          // Stuff to do
      });
}
}
```

What i'm missing here !

Comment: How about just using input type="range" ?  Set the min to 0 and the max value to the song length in seconds.  Then simply use the change event of the input control to seek to the correct position.

Comment: @HaukurHaf im aware but I am trying to find out how to do this without. Also it allows me for more custom work since I done most of GUI myself.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable Did you ever hear about this?

Comment: @AhmadAsjad ya I did but I want to avoid jquery

Comment: but you like the same thing?

Comment: @AhmadAsjad http://tympanus.net/Development/AudioPlayer/

Comment: I think you show use the trigger method it will fire what you need

Comment: use @cynicaljoy answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't add/remove the listener, just set a variable at trigger actions accordingly:

```
var isMousedown = false;

elem.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    isMousedown = true;
}

elem.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
    isMousedown = false;
});

elem.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    if (isMousedown) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do different stuff, or nothing
    }
});
```

You may even want to put the mousedown/mouseup listeners on the parent (or even the root element) to avoid scenarios where the mouseup happens outside of the target, if that is a possibility in your case.

Comment: so doing something like this isnt such a good idea? https://jsfiddle.net/v8qaxfeb/

Comment: What happens if your user isn't using fullscreen browser, moves their cursor out of the window, "unclicks" and moves their cursor back into focus? These are edge cases, but when adding/removing event listeners based off other events you run the risk of orphaned/duplicate listeners. Having defined listeners that are constant would be more manageable.

Comment: Could not find a more reliable code for this (even this solution is years old)